# the directory is already locked hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

**I am getting below error while starting hadoop:**

> 2015-09-04 08:49:05,648 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: **It appears that another node  854@ip-1-2-3-4 has already locked the storage directory: /mnt/xvdb/tmp/dfs/namesecondary
>   java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException**
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.tryLock(Storage.java:712)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:678)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:499)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$CheckpointStorage.recoverCreate(SecondaryNameNode.java:962)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:243)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
>   2015-09-04 08:49:05,650 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: **Cannot lock storage /mnt/xvdb/tmp/dfs/namesecondary. The directory is already locked**
>   2015-09-04 08:49:05,650 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Failed to start secondary namenode
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /mnt/xvdb/tmp/dfs/namesecondary. The directory is already locked
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:683)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:499)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$CheckpointStorage.recoverCreate(SecondaryNameNode.java:962)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:243)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.(SecondaryNameNode.java:192)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:671)
>   2015-09-04 08:49:05,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
>   2015-09-04 08:49:05,653 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
>   /************************************************************
>   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down SecondaryNameNode at ip-@ip-1-2-3-4/@ip-1-2-3-4
>   ************************************************************/

**Hadoop  version: 2.7.1(3 node cluster)**

**hdfs-site.xml configuration file:**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/mnt/xvdb/hadoop/dfs/data</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/mnt/xvdb/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have tried formatting name node as well, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to above problem here : http://misconfigurations.blogspot.in/2014/10/hadoop-initialization-failed-for-block.html

If there is any other solution,would like to have a look.

**P.S: I have deleted the directory pointed out by "dfs.datanode.data.dir" and it has erased all  data on HDFS but helped me to fix the issue. So You can use an alternate way, if has any, for fixing this issue.**