# Datanode keeps dying

Tags: hadoop, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am running hadoop 0.20.2 (yes it's a legacy app).
I have a simple master-slave setup with 2 nodes.
I can start up the cluster fine with jps command on master:

```
4513 TaskTracker
4225 DataNode
4116 NameNode
4565 Jps
4329 SecondaryNameNode
4410 JobTracker
```

And jps command on slave:

```
2409 Jps
2363 TaskTracker
2287 DataNode
```

However if I run a command which interacts with hdfs like:

```
hadoop dfs -ls /
```

it takes a couple of minutes and then one of the datanodes dies.
Looking in the log I can see this which is a known bug([the directory is already locked hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394167/the-directory-is-already-locked-hadoop)):

```
2017-07-05 16:12:59.986 INFO main org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage - Cannot lock storage /srv/shared/hadoop/dfs/data. The directory is already locked.
Cannot lock storage /srv/shared/hadoop/dfs/data. The directory is already locked.
```

I have tried stopping all daemons and deleting dfs/data and formatting the namenode. After doing that I can successfully start the cluster again with  everything up but as soon as I interact with hdfs or run a MR job a datanode dies.

The exact steps I am taking according to other posts are:
1. stop all daemons
2. delete dfs/data dir
3. run hadoop namenode -format
4. start all daemons

Not sure what else I can try.

Comment: Is `/srv/shared` a networks shared mounted folder? Is it shared by multiple data nodes?

Comment: Hi Remus, yes this is a shared mounted folder.

Comment: Not sure I reason why would you use a shared folder for HDFS storage but anyway, make sure **each data node uses a different folder on the shared storage**

Comment: Hi Remus, I wouldn't ;-) its a legacy app. Ok thanks , yes that makes sense.

Comment: Ie. node1 one has `dfs.datanode.data.dir` value `/srv/shared/node1/hadoop/dfs/data`, node2 uses `/srv/shared/node2/hadoop/dfs/data` and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remus!

Answer (score 0):

As Remus Rusanu correctly pointed out HDFS is stored on a shared mounted folder and that is the problem. Specifying separate data.dirs solves the problem.